# Is there a way to translate dynamic text in Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, translation

I understand that the `Play Framework (2.7)` allows [Internationalization](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaI18N) in which to display pre-written text but is there a way that it can translate blocks of text dynamically? For example; suppose that a user has written a review and another user wants to read that review in their own language. It's not practical to manually translate user reviews before making them accessible to other users. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Internationalization  feature in Play has nothing in common with translation at all, it's just provide infrastructure around ability of you app to show content based on user localisation preferences. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaI18N#Externalizing-messages:

> You can externalize messages in the conf/messages.xxx files.
> The default conf/messages file matches all languages. Additionally you can specify > language-specific message files such as conf/messages.fr or conf/messages.en-US.

Which means that you can have text files like

`conf/messages.en-US`:

```
example.message.id=Example message in US English
```

`conf/messages.fr-FR`:

```
example.message.id=Example message in French
```

and then retrieve particular message by it's id depending on languauge like:

```
val messagesApi: MessagesApi = //injected API
messagesApi("example.message.id")(lang)
```

So Play framework for you will choose proper file and read proper message for particular languague.

But content of files is your responsibility, Play does not translate nothing for you.

Comment: thanks ivan. So `Play` doesn't have anything out-of-the-box but do you know of any plugins/modules that anyone has developed. I can't find anything but worth an ask?

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris do you mean for translation? Well don't expect easy answer here - computer translation is whole science by itself: you can proceed with using SAAS like google translate or implement own translation, based on things like Moses: http://www.statmt.org/moses/ anyway it's not something easy to answer. Btw if my answer was helpful acceptance and upvote highly appreciated.